# Trailing off html text (with PHP)

Tags: php, html

Asking for the term or certain html/php code where you can trail off part of the text. I have a long description where id like to show just a small part of its intro and add the trailing off dots. By clicking on read more it redirects to its full article.

[image: 1]

Comment: Okay, you've defined your task. What have you tried to do to solve it? Are you using any framework?

Comment: you can use `substr` to limit how much text you fetch from a string, you can then build your own logic to append the ellipsis... https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [substr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

*substr — Return part of a string*

```
substr ( string $string , int $start, int $length )
```

Returns the string specified by start and end.

```
echo substr('abcdef', 1);     // bcdef
echo substr('abcdef', 1, 3);  // bcd
echo substr('abcdef', 0, 4);  // abcd
echo substr('abcdef', 0, 8);  // abcdef
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$text = "this is a long string of text that we need to snip";
$sniplength = 15;

echo substr($text,0,$sniplength)."...";
```